# var damage = Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * max)+1, min) what is the meaning first 'Math.max' and last ',min' here

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

```
var damage = Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * max)+1, min);
```

What is the meaning first `Math.max` and last `,min` here. Please explain the whole line.

Comment: Math.max is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and `min` is a number that would be the minimum result you want, `max` is the maximum you want - Math.random is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and Math.floor is documeted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) - so `damage` will be a random integer value between `min` and `max` inclusive

Comment: depending on the value of `min` this results in a random number skewed toward `min` - so, not an ideal random function if `min` is 10 and `max` is `20` for example ... half the values returned will be 10, and the other half distributed between 10 and 20

Comment: a better random function would be `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min`

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) is a function that, when passed a variable amount of numbers, returns the largest number:

```js
console.log(Math.max(1, 2, 3));
```

`min` in your code is the minimum number that `damage` can be - so it works out as (pseudocode):

```
set damage to the maximum number out of:
    A random number between 0 and 1, multiplied by max, rounded down,
    or min;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look up `Math.random` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random
>   number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1) with approximately
>   uniform distribution over that range — which you can then scale to
>   your desired **range**.

So here, the range is `max` and you are taking the `Math.floor` of the expression `Math.random() * max` and then adding 1 to it.

`Math.floor` will round the number produced to the largest integer less than or equal to a given result. So if the `Math.random() * max` results in say `5.95` the `Math.floor` will make the resulting number `5`.

Then at the end we are finding the maximum of the resulting number of the previous step and the `min` variable and assigning the result to the `damage` variable.

Answer (score 0):

[Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) is a build in object in javascript that has method and properties & here `[Math.max][2]` is use to find the largest of numbers. Math.floor & Math.random are also available methods

I have broken down the code into multiple lines, for ease of understanding

```js
function findMax(max, min) {
  let findRandom = Math.random() * max; // generate a random number
  // if it is a decimal number get the previous whole number
  let findLower = Math.floor(findRandom);
  // add one with the generated whole number
  let addOne = findLower + 1;
  // find the maximum between two numbers, one is generated & another is 
  // supplied as argument
  let damage = Math.max(addOne, min)
  return damage;
}
console.log(findMax(4, 1))
```